# HQL - Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I'm trying to match a hibernate entity via by DAO class, the first method works but the second 'findByMatchingName()' fails with the exception below. What's wrong with this clause '%?%'> ?

```
public class RunnerDaoImpl extends GenericDaoImpl implements RunnerDao
{
    protected Class<Runner> getEntityClass() {
        return Runner.class;
    }

    // Works
    public List<Runner> findByExactName(String name)
    {
        return super.getHibernateTemplate().find("from Runner r where concat(r.firstname,' ',r.surname) LIKE =",new String[]{name});
    }

    // Fails
    public List<Runner> findByMatchingName(String name)
    {
        return super.getHibernateTemplate().find("from Runner r where concat(r.firstname,' ',r.surname) LIKE '%?%'",new String[]{name});
    }
}
```

The exception

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based!
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.ParameterMetadata.getOrdinalParameterDescriptor(ParameterMetadata.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.ParameterMetadata.getOrdinalParameterExpectedType(ParameterMetadata.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.determineType(AbstractQueryImpl.java:421)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:393)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$30.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:918)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$30.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:1)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTemplate.java:912)
    at ie.bhaa.dao.RunnerDaoImpl.findByName(RunnerDaoImpl.java:15)
    at ie.bhaa.dao.RunnerDaoTest.findRunnerByName(RunnerDaoTest.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You need to add the `wildchar(%)` to the parameter and not the query.** So modify your second query as below.

```
// This will work!
public List<Runner> findByMatchingName(String name)
{
    return super.getHibernateTemplate().find(
    "from Runner r where concat(r.firstname,' ',r.surname) 
     LIKE ?",new String[]{"%"+name+"%"});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the `%` in the query parameter rather than in the query itself, so the parameter would become `"%" + name + "%"`.